# razor - binding issue with radio button

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am struggling to bind ans for radio button i am doing a small project.
I have two model Question and Answer. What i want to achive for pull a list of question and base on setting the user will have multiple choice or type the answer in a text box.  with the radio button i cant seem to bind the ans it geting a null object can someone please point me in the right direction.

```
@model List<Question.Models.Questionnaire>


@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Question List</h2>

@using(Html.BeginForm("GetAnswer","Home")) {


for(int i = 0;i < Model.Count;i++) {

    <text>@Model[i].Questions</text> <br />

    @Html.HiddenFor(M => M[i].QuestionID)

    if (@Model[i].MultipleChoice == false){

        @Html.TextBoxFor(M => M[i].Response) <br />

    } else {

          for(int j = 0;j < Model[i].GetAns.Count;j++) {
               <div>
              <text>@Model[i].GetAns[j].AnsText</text>
              @Html.RadioButtonFor(M => Model[i].QuestionID, Model[i].GetAns[j].AnswerId) <br />
               </div>
        }

        /*
        foreach(var ansOption in PossibleAns) {
          <div>
           @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => Model[i].QuestionID, ansOption.AnswerId)
           @Html.Label(ansOption.AnsText)
          </div>  
        }
         * */
        <br />
    }
}
<br />

  <input type="submit" name="submit" />
```

}

```
public class Questionnaire
{
    public Questionnaire() {
    }

    public int QuestionID  { get; set;}
    public string Title    { get; set;}
    public string Questions{ get; set;}
    public string Response { get; set;}
    public bool MultipleChoice { get; set;}

    public List<Answer> GetAns { set; get;}

}

 public class Answer  
 {
    public int AnswerId { get; set; }
    public string AnsText { get;set;}
    public Questionnaire Ques { get; set;}
 }


public class QuestionRepository
{

    public List<Questionnaire>
         GetQuestionnaire() {
             List<Questionnaire> q = new List<Questionnaire>();
             q.Add(new Questionnaire() {
                 QuestionID = 11, Title = "Geo", Questions = "Capital of England?", GetAns = GetAns(), MultipleChoice = true
             });
             q.Add(new Questionnaire() {
                 QuestionID = 22, Title = "Geo", Questions = "Capital of France", GetAns = GetAns()
             });
             q.Add(new Questionnaire() {
                 QuestionID = 33, Title = "Geo", Questions = "Capital of Cuba", GetAns = GetAns()
             });
             return q;
    }

    public List<Answer> GetAns() {

        List<Answer> ans = new List<Answer>();
        ans.Add(new Answer() {
            AnswerId = 1, AnsText = "london", Ques = new Questionnaire() {
                QuestionID = 11
            }
        });
        ans.Add(new Answer() {
            AnswerId = 2, AnsText = "paris", Ques = new Questionnaire() {
                QuestionID = 22
            }
        });
        ans.Add(new Answer() {
            AnswerId = 3, AnsText = "Havana", Ques = new Questionnaire() {
                QuestionID = 33
            }
        });

        return ans;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your radio buttons are binding to property `QuestionID` (and your overwriting the value of `QuestionID` with the selected `AnswerID` so nothing would make sense when you post back. Your class and property naming makes it a difficult to understand, but if your wanting to select one answer from a group of possible answers, then property `GetAns` just needs to be `List<string>` and then bind the selected answer to property `Response`. For example, for the first question (*"Capital of England?"*) where you seem to be wanting the choices to be *"london"*, *"paris"* or *"Havana"*, then the question should have a property

```
public List<string> PossibleAnswers { get; set; }
```

and in the controller

```
model.Questions[0].PossibleAnswers = new List<string>() { "london", "paris", "Havana" }
```

and in the view

```
for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) {
{

  if (@Model[i].MultipleChoice)
  {
    // Radio buttons for multiple choice
    foreach(string option in Model[i].PossibleAnswers)
    {
      <label>   
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m[i].Response, option})
        <span>@option</span>
      </label>
    }
  }
  else
  {
    // Textbox for answer
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m[i].Response)
  }
}
```

When you post back, the `Response` property will contain the text of the answer, either what been entered in the text box, or one of the possible answers if its a multiple choice question.

However, I suggest you need to rethink most of what your doing here, especially if your wanting to bind to an ID property of a multiple choice answer.