# Razor showing property name instead of value

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I Just start MVC and razor, i am having an issue for displaying data, the controller is return a list of collection data  in the view when im trying to display on the UI it showing the property name instead of the data.
for exmaple     @Html.LabelFor(M =>M[i].Questions) is suppose to show the question data but instead it showing the property name in the UI, i would be very greatful for someone to help me out.

[image]

```
 @model List<Question.Models.Questionnaire>
   @using System.Linq
     @{
     ViewBag.Title = "Index";
      Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
     }

 <h2>Question List</h2>

 @using(Html.BeginForm("GetAnswer","Home")) {


for(int i = 0;i < Model.Count;i++) {

    //<text>@Model[i].Questions</text> <br />

      @Html.HiddenFor(M => M[i].QuestionID)
      **@Html.LabelFor(M =>M[i].Questions)**

    if (@Model[i].MultipleChoice == false){

        @Html.TextBoxFor(M => M[i].Response) <br />

    } else {

        for(int j = 0;j < Model[i].GetAns.Count;j++) {
        <div>
        <text>@Model[i].GetAns[j].AnsText</text>
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(M =>M[i].Questions, Model[i].GetAns[j].AnswerId)
        </div>
        }
        <br />
    }
}


     public class Questionnaire
     {
        public Questionnaire() {
      }

    public int QuestionID  { get; set;}
    public string Title    { get; set;}
    public string Questions{ get; set;}
    public string Response { get; set;}
    public string Response1 {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public bool MultipleChoice { get; set;}

    public List<Answer>GetAns { set; get;}

}


 public class QuestionRepository
 {

    public List<Questionnaire>
         GetQuestionnaire() {
             List<Questionnaire> q = new List<Questionnaire>();
             q.Add(new Questionnaire() {
                 QuestionID = 11, Title = "Geo", Questions = "Capital of England?", GetAns = GetAns(), MultipleChoice = false, Response1="TEST"
             });
             q.Add(new Questionnaire() {
                 QuestionID = 22, Title = "Geo", Questions = "Capital of France", GetAns = GetAns(), MultipleChoice = false, Response1 = "TEST2"
             });
             q.Add(new Questionnaire() {
                 QuestionID = 33, Title = "Geo", Questions = "Capital of Cuba", GetAns = GetAns(), MultipleChoice = true, Response1 = "TEST3"
             });
             return q;
    }

    public List<Answer> GetAns() {

        List<Answer> ans = new List<Answer>();
        ans.Add(new Answer() { AnswerId = 1, AnsText = "london", Ques = new Questionnaire() { QuestionID = 11 } });
        ans.Add(new Answer() { AnswerId = 2, AnsText = "paris", Ques = new Questionnaire() {  QuestionID = 22 } });
        ans.Add(new Answer() { AnswerId = 3, AnsText = "Havana", Ques = new Questionnaire() { QuestionID = 33 }  });

        return ans;
    }



}


   public ActionResult Index()
    {

        var q = new QuestionRepository().GetQuestionnaire();

        return View(q);
    }
```

Comment: Side note: `Questions` feel like collection - either confusing name OR you should be rendering it as collection of some sort...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, If you look at [OP's previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254213/razor-binding-issue-with-radio-button), it gets even more confusing :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`@Html.LabelFor()` is for displaying the name of the property (or the value defined by `[Display(Name="...")]`), not the value of the property. If you want to display the value, then use

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m =>m[i].Questions)
```

Comment: .LabelFor() also adds the Label element, which may not be what one wants.

Answer (score 4):

That's what `Html.LabelFor()` does.  It's meant to create a label next to an input element, where the label has the field name and the input element has the value.

If you want the value in an input element, use something like `Html.TextBoxFor()` instead.  Or you might use `Html.DisplayFor()` to create a display element of some sort.  Or, if you just want the value emitted to the markup, just emit it directly:

```
@model.SomeProperty
```

You don't need to use the HTML helper methods to emit values directly, just bind that part of the markup directly to the model.